# Jquery ajax submit form without specifying data

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is it possible to submit a form with jquery without explicity having to set the data.

ie. I have the following form

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "DrawingWindow", FormMethod.Get, new {id="DrawingSearch"}))
   { %>
    <div>
        <%: Html.LabelFor( m=> m.DrawingNumberName, new {@class="dark_blue"}) %>
    </div>
    <div>
        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.DrawingNumberName)%>
        <%: Html.Submit("Search") %>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

and I would like to do something like the following:

```
 $('#drawingSearch').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $ajax({
                url: '<%:Url.Action("Search", "PID") %>',
                type: 'GET',
            })
    });
```

Now since I havent specified any data here I think the textbox I have wont be sent in the ajax request, is there a way to include it without having to give the textbox an id and make a data object to send as part of the request?

Comment: "make a data object" can you please explain this a bit.

Comment: why not just submit the form ajaxly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put it inside a form tag, and use the jquery serialize function.

```js
$('#drawingSearch').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var data = $('#myForm').serialize();

    $ajax({
        url: '<%:Url.Action("Search", "PID") %>',
        data: data,
        type: 'GET',
    })
});
```

In this way, you can put as many input fields inside the form as you would like, and not have to change the javascript/jQuery code.

Answer (score 0):

or can grab the value using `$('textarea').val()` without setting an `id` to textbox

```
$ajax({
        url: '<%:Url.Action("Search", "PID") %>',
        data: 'textVal='+$('textarea').val(),
        type: 'GET',
    })
```